# Why isn't onRestoreInstanceState called after onStart?

Tags: android

I am trying to test onRestoreInstanceState method and when (exactly) it is called . So I have followed these steps :

1. start my activity. `onCreate -- > onStart --> onResume` were called .
2. press Home button on the emulator . `onPause --> onSaveInstanceState --> onStop` were called .
3. Click the icon in the launcher and launch my activity again. `onRestart --> onStart --> onResume` were called .

My java code :

```
package com.test.demostate.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;


 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   private int visiters=0;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Log.d("TAG","onCreate");

   }

  @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
       Log.d("TAG","onPause");
  }

  @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       Log.d("TAG","onStop");
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       Log.d("TAG","onStart");
   }

   @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
       super.onRestart();
       Log.d("TAG","onRestart");

   }

    @Override
     protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
        visiters++;
        Log.d("TAG","onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("visiters",visiters);
        Log.d("TAG",visiters+" visiters  was saved ");
    }

    @Override
     protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        visiters=savedInstanceState.getInt("visiters");
         Log.d("TAG",visiters+" visiters was restored");
    }

     @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("TAG","onDestroy");
    }
}
```

From the docs : `Instead of restoring the state during onCreate() you may choose to implement onRestoreInstanceState(), which the system calls after the onStart() method .`

So onRestoreInstanceState is called

- after the activity was destroyed `onPause --> onStop --> onDestroy` then `onCreate --> onRestoreInstanceState --> onResume`( due to screen rotation for example )
- after the activity was stopped `onPause --> onStop --> onRestart --> onStart  --> onRestoreInstanceState --> onResume`( due to home icon pressing for example )

But why isn't it called after onStart ?

Thanks

Comment: "..which the system calls *after* the onStart() method." - Please write titles relevant to the problem.

Comment: @user2864740 , my question's title was edited  " Why isn't ..."

Comment: After step two, press home button again and click in your app opened. Try execute your app on the smartphone too.

Comment: @Lucas Santos it still doesn't work

Comment: Try change the orientation instead of pressing the home button.

Comment: According to my java code I am pretty sure that onRestoreInstanceState is called when the orientation is changed and that hapened in this order  `onPause --> onSaveInstanceState --> onStop --> onDestroy ` then ` onCreate --> onRestoreInstanceState --> onStart --> onResume ` . But i Want to know why it isn't called after onStart ( you can see steps in my question )

Comment: FYI, to help testing restoring state you can enable `Don't keep activities` in the developer options on your device.

Answer (score 1):

After `onStart()` only if `onSaveInstanceState()` has been called.

From the docs:

> This method is called after onStart() when the activity is being
>   re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in
>   savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use
>   onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes
>   convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done
>   or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default
>   implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a
>   restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).
>
> This method is called between onStart() and onPostCreate(Bundle).

[Activity#onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: ok understood .In my code i have called both  onSaveInstanceState  and onRestoreInstanceState . And i have tested if onRestoreInstanceState was called with Log.d method But nothing is shown ( i am using android studio 0.5.2 )

Comment: @JamesDaniel Did you save any state when overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`?

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation says about `onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

> This method is called after onStart() ***when the activity is being
>   re-initialized*** from a previously saved state, given here in
>   savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use
>   onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes
>   convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done
>   or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default
>   implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a
>   restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).
>
> This method is called between onStart() and onPostCreate(Bundle).

***When the activity is beign re-initialized?***

- When orientation of the device changes your activity is re-initialized.
- When there is another activity in front of your app and the OS kills your app for some reason, may be for example free resources.

Try change the orientation of emulator:

> Ctrl+F12

Look the [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/15703/60281) of user @GAThrawn

> Pressing the Home button you leave your app and go to the home screen,
>   whilst leaving your app running in the background. This is a bit like
>   switching between windows on a Windows PC.
>
> **Except that when your phone is running low on resources** like memory it
>   will start to close apps that are running in the background, so that
>   your phone has enough resources for what you're trying to do now.
>   Games are often amongst the first apps the phone will "kill" to save
>   resources as they often use a lot more memory and CPU than other apps.
>   This is why sometimes your game is still running paused, and sometimes
>   Android has closed it for you.

***So I can not prove my second argument, since it decides it is the OS, at least do not know how to prove.***

Comment: you just prove the first suggestion ( after the activity was destroyed ) and that's ok . But how about the second suggestion ( After the activity was stopped without being destroyed ) ?

Comment: I edited my answer, look. Please accept my answer if it was useful to him and healed your question.

Comment: Try press Home Button and kill your app, after reopen your app, look if this prove my second argument.