# onRestoreInstanceState is not getting called

Tags: android, bundle, android-lifecycle

i want to save the value of a textView when the App goes into onPause. so I implemented onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState. but as shown below in the logcat output, onRestoreInstanceState
is never called.

i know that both of onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState are not part of the App lifecycle, so why onSaveInstanceState is getting called while onRestoreInstanceState is not?
and how to call onRestoreInstanceState?

**code**:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Log.w(TAG, LogAnd.i("onResume", ""));

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (btAdapter == null) {
        tvStatus.setText("[" + SysUtils.getDeviceName() + "] no Bluetooth installed.");
    } else {
        tvStatus.setText("[" + SysUtils.getDeviceName() + "] Bluetooth installed.");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.w(TAG, LogAnd.i("onSaveInstanceState", ""));

    outState.putString("statusText", tvStatus.getText().toString());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.w(TAG, LogAnd.i("onRestoreInstanceState", ""));

    String status = savedInstanceState.getString("statusText");
    tvStatus.setText(status);
}
```

**logcat**:

```
08-23 18:36:31.544: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onResume:
08-23 18:36:31.904: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onPause:
08-23 18:36:32.694: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onSaveInstanceState:
08-23 18:36:34.014: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onResume:
08-23 18:36:42.904: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onPause:
08-23 18:36:43.784: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onSaveInstanceState:
08-23 18:36:43.784: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onStop:
08-23 18:36:50.084: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onStart:BT-Receiver Registered
08-23 18:36:50.084: W/MainActivity(32195): -> onResume:
```

Answer (score 2):

`onRestoreInstanceState()` is called only after `onStart()` and so it is not called after `onResume()`. Check this complete activity lifecycle.

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: same aspect like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130726/why-isnt-onrestoreinstancestate-called-after-onstart . How to load state if we just click home and than back to app ??App not killed in that case but data is lost...

Answer (score 2):

As [the official reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) says about `onSaveInstanceState`:

> This method is called before an activity may be killed

If there is **possibility** for an `Activity` to be killed, `onSaveInstanceState` will be called regardress of actually it will have been killed or not.

While `onRestoreInstanceState` is called when **actually** the `Activity` has been killed.

Therefore, if actually the `Activity` has not been killed, `onRestoreInstanceState` is not called.

Thus, asymmetry calling between `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` can be happen. If you want to make sure to  be called `onRestoreInstanceState`, you should surely kill your `Activity`.